# Estimate intercept and fixed effects with fixest's GLM function

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I'm trying to replicate Stata outputs that provide both constant and FEs.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do

```
> fixest::feglm(mpg ~ 1 + wt | cyl, mtcars)

GLM estimation, family = gaussian, Dep. Var.: mpg
Observations: 32 
Fixed-effects: cyl: 3
Standard-errors: Clustered (cyl) 
   Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|) 
wt -3.20561    1.18823 -2.69781  0.11431 
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
Log-Likelihood: -74.3   Adj. Pseudo R2: 0.252149
           BIC: 162.5     Squared Cor.: 0.837433
```

The idea of the "1" in my formula is to estimate the model
$$mpg_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 wt_i + \sum_j \beta_j cyl_{ij} + e_i$$

Instead of the model
$$mpg_i = \beta_1 wt_i + \sum_j \beta_j cyl_{ij} + e_i$$

Would that be possible with a "hack"?

The reason to use fixest is that it is much faster than

```
stats::glm(mpg ~ wt + as.factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
```

which estimates an intercept and the FEs but dropping one factor level that passes as the intercept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given one continuous predictor *wt* and one categorical predictor *cyl*, you propose two models, with and without intercept.

The model with an intercept is over-parameterized. The (global) intercept is redundant because each *cyl* level has its own intercept: fixed effect of *cyl_i* = intercept for all observations in the *cyl_i* group.

So in practice `fixest` discretely ignores the `+ 1` "hack" and fits the model without an intercept.

PS. A better way to write down the model is:
$$
E\{mpg_i\} = beta_{cyl_i} + beta_{wt} * wt
$$
This formula makes it explicit that the intercept is specific to each *cyl* level.

And we can check that this is indeed how fixest interprets the formula:

```r
library("fixest")

# Not necessary to fit the model but handy to compute the predictions by hand
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

fit <- feglm(mpg ~ wt | cyl, mtcars)

beta_cyl_i <- fixef(fit)$cyl[mtcars$cyl]
beta_wt_x_wt <- coef(fit)["wt"] * mtcars$wt

# We now know how to compute by hand the predictions that we get with `predict()`
beta_cyl_i + beta_wt_x_wt
#>        6        6        4        6        8        6        8        4 
#> 21.33650 20.51907 26.55377 19.42916 16.89262 18.64379 16.47590 23.76489 
#>        4        6        6        8        8        8        8        8 
#> 23.89311 18.70790 18.70790 14.87309 15.96300 15.80272 11.09046 10.53269 
#>        8        4        4        4        4        8        8        8 
#> 10.78593 26.93844 28.81373 28.10849 26.08896 16.63618 16.90865 15.61038 
#>        8        4        4        4        8        6        8        4 
#> 15.59435 27.78793 27.13078 29.14070 17.75814 20.85566 16.47590 25.07919
predict(fit)
#>  [1] 21.33650 20.51907 26.55377 19.42916 16.89262 18.64379 16.47590 23.76489
#>  [9] 23.89311 18.70790 18.70790 14.87309 15.96300 15.80272 11.09046 10.53269
#> [17] 10.78593 26.93844 28.81373 28.10849 26.08896 16.63618 16.90865 15.61038
#> [25] 15.59435 27.78793 27.13078 29.14070 17.75814 20.85566 16.47590 25.07919
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>